# CSS: behaviour not being included

Tags: css, behavior, css3pie

I am attempting to use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to render some CSS3 styles in legacy browsers. I am using wordpress and have implemented it as so (I have taken it out of an ie conditional so I can test it in firebug):

```
<style type="text/css">
        #breadcrumbs,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li,
        #searchform,
        #searchform #input, 
        #searchform #submit {behavior: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/PIE.htc");}</style>
```

This outputs:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #breadcrumbs,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul,
        #breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li,
        #searchform,
        #searchform #input, 
        #searchform #submit {behavior: url("http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/PIE.htc");}</style>
```

http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/PIE.htc resolves correctly in the browser, however the file is not loading and no request is made for it from the firebug net panel.

Does anyone know what is happening? A live example can be found at http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/

Comment: make the element `position:relative`

Comment: @AndreasWinter that doesn't change anything except break the layout. PIE.htc isn't even being requested by the browser, it's not that it isn't functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this but
I hope this will help you

style type="text/css">

```
#breadcrumbs,
#breadcrumbs ul#parent,
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul,
#breadcrumbs ul#parent li ul li,
#searchform,
#searchform #input, 
#searchform #submit {behavior: url("http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/PIE.htc");}</style>
```

Comment: Thanks I made a silly mistake with the end bracket, but it still doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the path from your server (dir), not the URL. For example, `/var/www/myproject/path/to/my/PIE.htc`.

Comment: absolute paths should work just fine, many people are using them to load .htc files in wordpress themes. Using this format doesn't make it request the file.

Comment: And if you try to give the path relative to the HTML document that uses it? As you can see [there](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths), it seems to be a known issue. Maybe you should also specify the content-type within your `.htaccess` file, as explained [there](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type).